# How to run more than one docker-compose simultaneously with docker toolbox

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I have installed docker toolbox on windows 10 (https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/)

Then I have created a directory for my project, with docker-compose.yml file (https://docs.docker.com/compose/)

I run MINGW64 then cd to the directory and hit `docker-compose up` to start the images for the project. Note: MINGW64 terminal is now showing the logs and I can't hit other commands.

Now, say I have to create another project: I will create another directory with another docker-compose.yml file.

How to run both the projects simultaneously? In this situation, I can't write on MINGW64 terminal to run the second project while the first project is running.

Hwo to run two projects (with two different docker-compose.yml files) simultaneously, with docker toolbox?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by simultaneously, you mean from a single command, you could go for something like that :

```
$ docker-compose -f path/to_your/first_compose.yml up -d && docker-compose up -d
```

Provided that you have your second compose file in current folder.

If you mean from a single `docker-compose` call, I don't think there's a way to do it.

The fact that you didn't get interaction on the CLI back is due to the way you launched the your compose. By providing the '-d' flag, you detach the containers' output from current shell. Example with a gitlab setup with 3 containers:

```
$ docker-compose -f dev/docker/docker-gitlab/docker-compose.yml up -d
Creating docker-gitlab_postgresql_1 ... done
Creating docker-gitlab_redis_1      ... done
Creating docker-gitlab_gitlab_1     ... done
$ do_something # you get back interactive shell
```

You can still access the output of the containers with `docker-compose` if required, the same as with `docker`, with the `log` command.